# Standard way to do asyntask in order with promise

Tags: asynchronous, promise

All:

I am pretty new to promise, what I want to do are:

[1] Download file A, when A downloaded, then download file B, after B is ready,  then download load C.

[2] Make a function to download file A, no matter how many times it been called, it only down file once.

[1] and [2] are not related tasks. You can help me with either one of them or Both.

Could anyone give me a simple example with promise?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you writing in node.js?  Or in browser?  Or in some other environment.  We can't offer code without knowing which environment.  Have you tried any code?  Which promise library are you using?

Comment: @jfriend00 I am planning do it in node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Bluebird promise library in node.js, here are three approaches:

```
// load and promisify modules
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));
```

Purely Sequential, each step coded separately

```
// purely sequential
fs.readFileAsync("file1").then(function(file1) {
    // file1 contents here
    return fs.readFileAsync("file2");
}).then(function(file2) {
    // file2 contents here
    return fs.readFileAsync("file3");    
}).then(function(file3) {
    // file3 contents here
}).catch(function(err) {
    // error here
});
```

Read all in parallel, collect results when they are all done

```
// read all at once, collect results at end
Promise.map(["file1", "file2", "file3"], function(filename) {
    return fs.readFileAsync(filename);
}).then(function(files) {
    // access the files array here with all the file contents in it
    // files[0], files[1], files[2]
}).catch(function(err) {
    // error here
});
```

Read sequential from an array

```
// sequential from an array
Promise.map(["file1", "file2", "file3"], function(filename) {
    return fs.readFileAsync(filename);
}, {concurrency: 1}).then(function(files) {
    // access the files array here with all the file contents in it
    // files[0], files[1], files[2]
}).catch(function(err) {
    // error here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. This helps. Could you give some examples with built-in promise in AngularJS or the node promise module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise