# Node - Callback second http.request based on result of the first

Tags: node.js, xmlhttprequest

I'm calling an API with http.request in NodeJs.

The call is meant to create a new item on the external service. For that to happen, a `label` parameter needs to be supplied. If it succeeds, it returns the status code 200 and the newly created item in JSON format. If the item already exists however, it returns a 404. Getting the item requires the call to be made to a different method.

Here is how I have implemented it:

```
function logError(err) {
    console.log(err)
}

function doSomething(chunk) {
    console.log(chunk)
}

if (var == true) {

    var domain = 'domain',
        port = 80,
        pathNew = '/api/v2/new?label=' + label + '&api_key=' + process.env.API_KEY,
        pathGet = '/api/v2/get?label=' + label + '&api_key=' + process.env.API_KEY,
        method = 'GET';         

    http.request({
        host: domain,
        port: port,
        path: pathNew,
        method: method
    }, function(res) {

        res.setEncoding('utf8');

        if( res.statusCode == '404') {

            http.request({
                host: domain,
                port: port,
                path: pathGet,
                method: method
            }, function(res2) {

                res2.setEncoding('utf8');

                res2.on('data', doSomething);

            }).on('error', logError).end();

        }

        res.on('data', doSomething);

    }).on('error', logError).end();
```

I realize this it probably not the optimal way to do this. How can I do this in a more streamlined way?

Comment: This won't even work the way you have it.  You must change `res2.on('data', doSomething(chunk));` to `res2.on('data', doSomething);` and same for other `.on()` handlers.  The way you show calls the function immediately rather than passes a function reference that can be called later.  Also, `consol.log(chunk)` should be `console.log(chunk)`

Comment: Still need the help though :)

Comment: This is the correct general approach.  Is there a specific problem you want help with?  The [request](https://github.com/request/request) module might make this slightly easier.

Comment: I thought there may be a better way to do this without going to callback hell, perhaps with `async`

Comment: Embedding a second operation in one callback is hardly callback hell.  You can chain or sequence async operations with either promises or libraries like async.  To use promises, you would have to first "promisify" the interfaces you are using so you can use promises with them.  Once promisified, you could use `request(...).then(function(first) return request(...));`  It still has the second operation in a callback (promises are still callbacks), but it is streamlined a bit.

Comment: FYI, some examples from an answer I provided yesterday [Standard way to do asyntask in order with promise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28998705/standard-way-to-do-asyntask-in-order-with-promise/29000674#29000674).